# ¿Cómo transformar columna en un nuevo vector?

Tags: r

Tengo esta tabla

```
id_match period license_licenseAbbrev type_normalized_description
     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>                      
1   102722      1 J. Parra              Starting Five              
2   102722      1 P. Ribas              Starting Five              
3   102722      1 D. Willis             Starting Five              
4   102722      1 V. Brodziansky        Starting Five              
5   102722      1 G. Vives              Starting Five
```

y me gustaría añadir una columna con los 5 nombres separados por comas en un solo vector que se repitiera todas las filas, tal que así y no sé cómo

```
 id_match period license_licenseAbbrev type_normalized_description nueva                                                       
     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>                       <chr>                                                       
1   102722      1 J. Parra              Starting Five               J. Parra,  P. Ribas,  D. Willis,  V. Brodziansky,  G. Vives,
2   102722      1 P. Ribas              Starting Five               J. Parra,  P. Ribas,  D. Willis,  V. Brodziansky,  G. Vives,
3   102722      1 D. Willis             Starting Five               J. Parra,  P. Ribas,  D. Willis,  V. Brodziansky,  G. Vives,
4   102722      1 V. Brodziansky        Starting Five               J. Parra,  P. Ribas,  D. Willis,  V. Brodziansky,  G. Vives,
5   102722      1 G. Vives              Starting Five               J. Parra,  P. Ribas,  D. Willis,  V. Brodziansky,  G. Vives,
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas es agrupar las columnas y concatenar una sola de ellas, si usas `tidyverse`, puedes hacer algo así:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by_at(vars(-license_licenseAbbrev)) %>% 
  mutate(license_licenseAbbrev = paste(license_licenseAbbrev, collapse = ', '))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id_match, period, type_normalized_description [1]
  id_match period license_licenseAbbrev                     type_normalized_descri~
     <int>  <int> <chr>                                     <chr>                  
1   102722      1 J. Parra, P. Ribas, D. Willis, V. Brodzi~ Starting Five          
2   102722      1 J. Parra, P. Ribas, D. Willis, V. Brodzi~ Starting Five          
3   102722      1 J. Parra, P. Ribas, D. Willis, V. Brodzi~ Starting Five          
4   102722      1 J. Parra, P. Ribas, D. Willis, V. Brodzi~ Starting Five          
5   102722      1 J. Parra, P. Ribas, D. Willis, V. Brodzi~ Starting Five
```

Con códijo R estándar, puedes hacer algo parecido, agrupas y luego unes los grupos a cada fila del `df` original:

```
grouped <- aggregate(license_licenseAbbrev ~ ., 
                     df,
                     paste,
                     collapse=', ')

df$license_licenseAbbrev <- merge(df, grouped, by=c("id_match"))$license_licenseAbbrev.y
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que usar la función `paste` con el argumento `collapse`

```
df<-read.table(text = "
id_match period license_licenseAbbrev type_normalized_description
102722      1 'J. Parra'              'Starting Five'              
102722      1 'P. Ribas'             'Starting Five'              
102722      1 'D. Willis'             'Starting Five'              
102722      1 'V. Brodziansky'        'Starting Five'              
102722      1 'G. Vives'              'Starting Five' 
    ",  header = T)

#Pegar todos los nombres collapsando la columna con coma y espacio
paste(df$license_licenseAbbrev,collapse=", ")

#Crear la nueva variable en el df
df$nueve<-paste(df$license_licenseAbbrev,collapse=", ")
df
```